# Is random effects model in meta-analysis a Bayesian approach?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

Unlike fixed effect model meta analysis, assumption in the random effects is that the effect size of an individual study deviates from the true effect, not only because of the sampling error but also due to the fact that even the true effect size of that study is only part of an over arching distribution of true effect sizes (Borenstein 2011). So, it is assumed that there is no one true effect size, but a distribution of true effect sizes, isn't this a Bayesian approach, unlike frequentist, where true effect size is considered constant?

I do not understand the intricacies of Bayesian vs frequentist, so please highlight if I am wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have correctly observed, both in meta-analysis and beyond, a frequentist mixed model does something similar to a Bayesian approach. Namely, it assumes a parameter not to have a fixed value, but rather to have been randomly drawn from some probability distribution (in practice: almost always a normal distribution with mean $0$ and unknown variance).

However, this is not the same as a Bayesian approach, which has no 'fixed effects'. In a fully Bayesian approach, every parameter has some underlying probability distribution. The Bayesian equivalent of a frequentist mixed model would be a [Bayesian hierarchical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling).

Comment: Very nice answer (+1)! I don't think I have seen such a succinct explanation of the difference between a mixed model and a Bayesian hierarchical model before.